# C# trouble using System.Random values

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to create random numbers and then employ this box muller algorithm I found.  The problem I am running into is doing any sort of mathematical operations using System.Random values.  I can't take square roots, logs or mix them with float values.  Here's my code for this random distribution.  I've been thinking on it for a few days and can't come up with anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Random rand1 = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("999 Doubles1.");
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 999; ctr++)
            Console.Write("{0,8:N3}", rand1.NextDouble());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Random rand2 = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("999 Doubles2.");
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= 999; ctr++)
            Console.Write("{0,8:N3}", rand2.NextDouble());
        Console.WriteLine();

        float mu = .75F;
        float sigma = .1F;

        float z1 = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(rand1)) * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * rand2);
        float z2 = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(rand1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * rand2);
        float x1 = mu + z1 * sigma;
        float x2 = mu + z2 * sigma;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't take the square root of a negative number (unless you are using complex numbers). also, you can't use a random object to pass to a function that expects a number!

Comment: You're creating two instances of `Random`, which is a bad idea. Create one instance, and call `NextDouble()` multiple times

Comment: -1: No compiler error message quoted, making it harder to see what you feel stuck on the most.

Answer (score 8):

Look at this code:

```
 Math.Log(rand1)
```

That's not trying to take the log of a random number... it's trying to take the log of a random number *generator*. You need something like:

```
double randomNumber = rand1.NextDouble();
// Code using Math.Log(randomNumber)
```

The concept of performing numerical operations on the random number generator itself doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I can't help wondering that if anyone else but Jon answered identically, they would not get so many upvotes.

Comment: @MitchWheat If it makes you feel any better the rep cap ends up gobbling up the vast majority of the votes anyway.

Comment: @Servy Would be interesting to know how much reputation Jon would have without the daily cap :). Is there any way?

Comment: @halex The data exists, yes.  You can see all of the related info on the `reputation` tab.  There's probably a query somewhere you could do that would give you the data programmatically such that you could avoid counting it by hand.

Comment: @halex: **1884579** http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/24898/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap-fixed

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for the link. Incredible :) P.S. Would upvote one of your answers for your comment, but you reached daily cap too. What a pity :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
            double double1 = rand1.NextDouble();
            double double2 = rand1.NextDouble();

            double z1 = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(double1)) * Math.Sin(2 * Math.PI * double2);
            double z2 = Math.Sqrt(-2 * Math.Log(double1)) * Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * double2);
            double x1 = mu + z1 * sigma;
            double x2 = mu + z2 * sigma;
```